# How to calculate the value needed to branch two points in IDA pro?

Tags: ida, arm, patching, ios, hex

I need to find how to get the value to make a branch between two points in IDA Pro, but I can’t figure it out. For more context: the instructions I’m following says “Calculate the value needed to do a branch from 176E4 to 1768C, which will be D2 E7”. How do they get D2 E7 from 176E4 and 1768C? Is there a math formula or is there somewhere in IDA where they find this? It's arm little endian.
Thank you

Comment: who's "they"? also, which ARM?

Comment: “They” is whoever wrote the guide I referenced, and it’s arm little endian.

Comment: got a link to the guide?

Comment: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Tutorial:Odysseus_Bundles#ASR_Patch 
Yes. The part I’m referencing is under asr patch

Answer (score 1):

This is an unconditional branch (thumb)

It is encoded as `11100`|`signed 11-bit immediate offset`

```
E    7    D    2  
1110 0111 1101 0010
```

so your 11-bit offset is 0b11111010010.  This is sign extended to -46

The operation is:
`PC = PC + (SignExtend(signed_immed_11) << 1)`
where the first PC contains the address of the branch plus 4.

0x176E4 + 4 + (-46 * 2) == 0x1768C

Comment: How do I get D2 E7 if I’m starting with 0x176E4 and 0x1768C?

Comment: this is basic algebra at this point `SRC + 4 + (X * 2) == DEST` solve for X.  `(0x1768C - 0x176E4 - 4) / 2` is a signed 11-bit number prepended by `11100`

Answer (score 0):

PC = current Instruction pointer + instruction length
PC = IP + 4
PC = 0x176E4 + 4  == 176E8

destination = 0x1768C

offset is encoded as a signed number of ((destination - PC)>>1)

```
:\>python -c "print(hex((0x1768c-0x176e8)>>1))
-0x2e
```

unconditional jump B can be encoded from **E0 00 to E7 FF**
==> E + (0x0 to 0x7ff ) == 0b1110 + (0b00000000000 .. 0b11111111111

**E0 00 to E3 FF** ARE FORWARD JUMPS FROM PC
**E4 00 TO E7 FF** ARE BACKWARD JUMPS FROM PC
-0X2E IS A BACKWARD JUMP
SO SUBTRACT **0X2E FROM 0X800** TO GET 0X7D2

using capstone and python

```
import capstone
cs = capstone.Cs(capstone.CS_ARCH_ARM , capstone.CS_MODE_THUMB)
cs.Detail = True
inp = [b'\x00\xe0',b'\x01\xe0',b'\x02\xe0',b'\xff\xe3',b'\x00\xe4',b'\xff\xe7',b'\xd2\xe7']
for j in range(0,len(inp),1):
    dis = cs.disasm( inp[j],  0x176e4)
    for i in dis:
        print(i.bytes ,("0x%x:\t" % i.address),("%s %s" %(i.mnemonic, i.op_str)))
```

executed

```
:\>python arm.py
bytearray(b'\x00\xe0') 0x176e4:  b #0x176e8
bytearray(b'\x01\xe0') 0x176e4:  b #0x176ea
bytearray(b'\x02\xe0') 0x176e4:  b #0x176ec
bytearray(b'\xff\xe3') 0x176e4:  b #0x17ee6
bytearray(b'\x00\xe4') 0x176e4:  b #0x16ee8
bytearray(b'\xff\xe7') 0x176e4:  b #0x176e6
bytearray(b'\xd2\xe7') 0x176e4:  b #0x1768c <<<<<<<<<<
```